# Main Activity resets after opening another Activity

Tags: java, android, xml

I've a newbie question about activities. I've a Main_Activity with some layout, options and graphics that I change and update. When I launch another Activity from my Main_Activity it opens, then when I want to back to my previous Main_Activity I've found that is resetted like I've just opened my app.

I'm using this code to launch my second activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Main_activity.this, Monitor_Activity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

How I can solve this problem?

I've read that an Activity goes in onPause an, I suppose, it keeps it's situation.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is resetted like I've just opened my app"?

Answer (score 0):

Android will always recreate the activity unless you specify it in your manifest using this:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

So your activity would be like:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
```

But be careful, because it won't work if the returning activity is not on the top of the back stack.

Comment: So, if I want to have more activities and keep the state of all activities I can't do that? Just one activity?

Comment: You can define a specific **android:launchMode** on every activity you need. Take a look at this post for further explanation about this:

http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en

Answer (score -1):

Just implement [onSaveInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) and [onRestoreInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)).

Take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).